# compile command across emacs sessions

Tags: emacs, compilation

how do i maintain a compile command across emacs sessions for a given file?

so, suppose I have file1.x, and I would like to use tool XComp to compile it. To do this, I need to run the following hypothetical command:

```
Xcomp file1.x && extract file1.x && Xlink file1.obj
```

So I do M-x compile, and write that thing. Now I have it available until I close emacs. How do I make that compile command persistent across emacs sessions, maybe a

```
% -*-
```

line somewhere? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable is "compile-command" so you could put this on the first line in your file:

```
// -*- compile-command: "Xcomp file1.x && extract file1.x && Xlink file1.obj" -*-
```

You may want to change the "//" for whatever you need to do for comments.